# Distance on thumbnails in columns in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is the markup I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="thumbnail col-md-12">
            <h3><a href="#">Title</a>
            <p>Some Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail col-md-6">
            <h3><a href="#">Title</a>
            <p>Some Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I preview this, it look like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNHBJ.png]

I've tried several solutions, but none of them worked, if I add a margin to the thumbnail/columns it just puts the right thumbnail under the left one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **correct way** to use thumbnails with content in bootstrap is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-...">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Bootstrap thumbnail custom content](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails-custom-content)

Bootstrap has an **offset** system:

[Bootsrap offset](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

which can be used for a solution:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <h3><a href="#">Title</a></h3>
                <p>Some Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <h3><a href="#">Title</a></h3>
                <p>Some Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you use e.g.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        thumbnail
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        thumbnail
    </div>
</div>
```

with a margin the two columns don't stay in one row. Because 6 + 6 = 12 and in bootstrap that fits the whole row. If you add some margin, it would be too long!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
<div class="thumbnail col-md-12">
```

To:

```
<div class="thumbnail col-md-6">
```

End result:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="thumbnail col-md-6">
            <h3><a href="#">Title</a>
            <p>Some Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail col-md-6">
            <h3><a href="#">Title</a>
            <p>Some Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```